# Как запомнить выполнение методов?

Tags: c#, .net, проектирование

Есть класс, например такой

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Method1(params)
    {

    }
    public void Method2(params)
    {

    }
    public void Method3(params)
    {

    }
}
```

Далее где то в коде по запросу пользователя вызываются методы у одного из экземпляров в произвольном порядке. Нажал пользователь нужную кнопочку, выполнился метод.

```
theMyClass.Method1(params);
theMyClass.Method2(params);
theMyClass.Method1(params);
theMyClass.Method3(params);
*****
```

Это должно где то сохраняться, чтобы была возможность выполнить те же методы в том же порядке для другого экземпляра класса `MyClass`.

Я подозреваю, что сохранять в очередь нужно команды, а потом выполнять их с другим параметром. Но прежде чем я это реализую, хотелось бы узнать, есть ли иные способы?

Comment: Почитайте про паттерн Command, по-моему, это как раз Ваша тема

Comment: @qzavyer, до конца дочитайте, пожалуйста

Comment: Есть способ через `Reflection.MethodBase` хранить ссылку на метод, обьект, и массив параметров для `Invoke(object , params[] )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, как-то так:

```
class MethodPack
{
    List<Action<MyClass>> methods = new List<Action<MyClass>>();
    public void Add(Action<MyClass> a) => methods.Add(a);
    public void Execute(MyClass obj)
    {
        foreach (var method in methods)
            method(obj);
    }
}
```

Теперь ваша кнопка должна запускать такой код:

```
MethodPack pack = new MethodPack();
MyClass firstObj = new MyClass();

void CallThisForButtonA()
{
    Action<MyClass> a = obj => obj.Method1(1, 2, 3);
    pack.Add(a);
    a(firstObj);
}

void CallThisForButtonB()
{
    Action<MyClass> a = obj => obj.Method2(6, "ромашка", 7);
    pack.Add(a);
    a(firstObj);
}
```

и так далее.

Когда нужно применить последовательность к другому экземпляру, пишете:

```
MyClass secondObj = ...;
pack.Execute(secondObj);
```

(Да, класс `MethodPack` можно сделать обобщённым.)

Comment: Кое что не понял. Что делает эта строка? `Action<MyClass> a = obj => obj.Method1(1, 2, 3);
`

Comment: @iRumba: Она создаёт функцию, которая по объекту `obj` типа `MyClass` выполняет код `obj.Method1(1, 2, 3)`. И помещает эту функцию в переменную `a`.

Comment: ну да, все таки с командами будет красивее... Хотя это должно работать быстрее

Comment: @iRumba: А как было бы с командами? Я что-то не смог придумать.

Comment: Был в отпуске :)  Ну команда - это экземпляр класса. А значит команду можно засунуть в коллекцию (очередь) и выполнить в любое время в любом месте, вызвав ее Executed с нужными параметрами. Как и где хранить эти параметры зависит от конкретной задачи. Если это методы во вью модели (реакция на действия пользователя), то тут вообще все просто. Практическая реализация - запись макроса. А если это методы модели, тут сложнее, но тоже разрешимо. так как меня интересует первый вариант, над вторым пока думать не хочется.

Comment: @iRumba: Ну так `Action<...>` — тоже экземпляр класса, точно такой же как и команда, и их тоже можно где угодно и когда угодно вызвать. // С возвращением!

Comment: Реализация команды подразумевает CanExecute, а в случае с Action мне придется допиливать этот механизм. К тому же я могу создать свою собственную реализацию команды, которая во время Executed будет наполнять очередь и не придется писать лишний код внутри каждого метода

Comment: Но в целом хорошая альтернатива. При чуть меньших требованиях я бы ее использовал.

Comment: @iRumba: А, ну это да, раз нужен CanExecute, тут команда как раз прекрасно ложится.